# EV SSL in Chrome Error “Insecure <form> call”

Tags: php, html, ssl

I have installed EV SSL on my [site](http://www.smartteck.co.uk/). But in chrome it isnt showing any padlock sign.

i checked the site for ssl scan [here](https://www.whynopadlock.com/check.php) and it is giving error

```
Insecure < form > call. Found on line # 2243 in file: www.smartteck.co.uk/index.html
```

but i can not figure out what is on ine 2243 the only form i have is newsletter signup in my footer and i can not see any problem with that.

can any one tell me what is wrong there?

my newsletter code:

```
<div id="subscribe-form" class="clearer">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <div>
            <label for="newsletter"><?php echo $this->__('Newsletter') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button btn-inline"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
    new Varien.searchForm('newsletter-validate-detail', 'newsletter', '<?php echo $this->helper('newsletter')->__('Enter your email address') ?>');
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<form`-tag which has an action which a hard-coded `http://`-URL as destination (`action`). I suppose Chrome does not show the padlock as users using this form will be redirected from https to http loosing their privacy.

Open the web console in Chrome to see any warning there.

Change http to https in `<form id="newsletter-validate-detail" method="post" action="http://www.smartteck.co.uk/newsletter/subscriber/new/">` or use a protocol agnostic form: `<form id="newsletter-validate-detail" method="post" action="//www.smartteck.co.uk/newsletter/subscriber/new/">` which will work for http and https.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, can you tell me where is this code located in my magento site?

Comment: I'm sorry, no. But that's another question.

Comment: i have set magento to use https from its settings and in .httaccess file as well. i will add my newsletter code in question now. thanks

Comment: @shafiq Please accept this answer if it helped you. That's the way to say thanks on StackOverflow.

Comment: i did not resolve the issue with your solution, if you can read my code above and elaborat it further i would be more then happy to accept the answer.

Comment: Well, that's another question.